# Email extraction starts and ends with unwanted characters (python)

Tags: python, regex

So I have a program that extracts emails and phone numbers.
I have ran it, and phone numbers come out fine. However the emails will keep resulting in: 
ex: 3465Usjohnson@astate.eduUProvost instead of sjohnson@astate.edu
The surround text that it is being extracted from:
870-972-3465Usjohnson@astate.eduUProvost and Vice ChancellorDr. Lynita Cooksey870-972-2 030 870-972-2036Ulcooksey@astate.edu

In the actual PDF there is whiteness and spacing, but when copy and pasted there is no space between them and hence my resulting email.(it would look like:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdxNv.png)

```
#! python 3

import re, pyperclip

# Regex for phone numbers
phoneRegex = re.compile(r'''
# 860-555-3951, 555-3951, (860) 555-3951, 555-3951 ext 12345, ext. 12345, x12345
(
((\d\d\d)|(\(\d\d\d\)))?    #area code (optional)
(\s|-)              #first seperator
\d\d\d              #first 3 digits
-                   #second seperator
\d\d\d\d            #last 4 digits
(((ext(\.)?\s)|x)   #Extension-words (optional)
(\d{2,5}))?         #Extension - numbers (optional)
)
''', re.VERBOSE)


#Regex for Emails
emailRegex = re.compile(r'''
#some._+thing@(/d{2,5}))?.com

[a-zA-Z0-9_.+]+   #Name part 
@    #@ symbol
[a-zA-Z0-9_.+]+ #domain


''', re.VERBOSE)


#pyperclip get text off 
text = pyperclip.paste()



#extract
extractedPhone = phoneRegex.findall(text)
extractedEmail = emailRegex.findall(text)

allPhoneNumbers = []
for phoneNumber in extractedPhone:
    allPhoneNumbers.append(phoneNumber[0])


#copy to clipboard
results = '\n'.join(allPhoneNumbers) + '\n'.join(extractedEmail)
pyperclip.copy(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

So because I don't have your original text, I'm just going to use a string from your example.

See if the following two regexes might work for you. I also include a third which is a bit more precise.

`'(?<=\dU)[\w]+@[\w\.]+?(?=U|\s|$)'`

.

`'(?<=\dU)[\w]+@[\w]+\.[\w]+?(?=U|\s|$)'`

.

**Example Tests**

```
>>> import re


>>> string = '''3465Usjohnson@astate.eduUProvost instead of sjohnson@astate.edu The surround text that it is being extracted from: 870-972-3465Usjohnson@astate.eduUProvost and Vice ChancellorDr. Lynita Cooksey870-972-2 030 870-972-2036Ulcooksey@astate.edu'''


>>> re.findall('(?<=\dU)[\w]+@[\w\.]+?(?=U|\s|$)', string)

#Output
['sjohnson@astate.edu', 'sjohnson@astate.edu', 'lcooksey@astate.edu']




>>> re.findall('(?<=\dU)[\w]+@[\w]+\.[\w]+?(?=U|\s|$)', string)

#Output
['sjohnson@astate.edu', 'sjohnson@astate.edu', 'lcooksey@astate.edu']
```

.

**To be a bit more precise, because the emails all end in `.edu`**

`'(?<=\dU)[\w]+@[\w]*\.edu(?=U|\s|$)'`

.

**Example Test**

```
>>> string = '''3465Usjohnson@astate.eduUProvost instead of sjohnson@astate.edu The surround text that it is being extracted from: 870-972-3465Usjohnson@astate.eduUProvost and Vice ChancellorDr. Lynita Cooksey870-972-2 030 870-972-2036Ulcooksey@astate.edu'''


>>> re.findall('(?<=\dU)[\w]+@[\w]*\.edu(?=U|\s|$)', string)

#Output
['sjohnson@astate.edu', 'sjohnson@astate.edu', 'lcooksey@astate.edu']
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm very new.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Python myself. If the text is specifically extracted from '**astate.edu**' website, I think you could use this regex:

```
text='70-972-3465Usjohnson@astate.eduUProvost and Vice ChancellorDr. Lynita Cooksey870-972-2 030 870-972-2036Ulcooksey@astate.edu'    
import re
email= re.findall('[a-z]+\@\w+\.edu',text)
#output
['sjohnson@astate.edu', 'lcooksey@astate.edu']
```

Good luck!